# JSON Serialize / Deserialize generic type with google-gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

Well, I have to confess I'm not good at generic type in Java

I've written a JSON serialize/deserialize class in C# using `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
    private static JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    public static T LoadFromJSONString<T>(string strRequest)
    {
        return js.Deserialize<T>(strRequest);
    }

    public static string DumpToJSONString<T>(T rq)
    {
        return js.Serialize(rq);
    }
```

It works well in C#. Now I'm trying to convert, or atleast, write another JSON serialize/deserialize class in Java. I've tried **flexjson** and **google-gson** but I don't know how to specify <T> in Java.

Could someone here help me? Btw, I prefer **google-gson**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java you must pass actual type-erased class, not just type parameter, so data binders know what type to use; so something like:

```
public static T LoadFromJSONString<T>(string strRequest, Class<T> type)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(strRequest, type);
}
```

but this is usually just needed for deserialization; when serializing, you have an instance with a class which libraries can use.

Btw, one other good Java JSON library you might want to consider using is [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org); however, for this particular example all libraries you mention should work.

Comment: Hmm, but suppose I only have class info as string, for example `String clazz = "com.example.Response"`, so how can I use this code?

Comment: You can use Class.forName("com.example.Response") to find it.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried. But the thing is that, when I use `Class.forName()`, the return type must be `Object` instead of `Response`, which I have to state clearly like this: `Response rp = (Response) LoadFromJSONString(resString, Class.forName("com.example.Response"))`

Comment: Since Class.forName() returns a Class<?>, you do need to do some casting; but while ugly, this does not prevent it from working. Interfaces typically require type parameter so that explicit passing of classes (Response.class is of type Class<Response>) is compatible with type parameter; but it is more of a nice to have feature.
So you must pass the Class to bind to; type parameter T is not enough for Java to figure out actual real type.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking this through I don't think there is a way to solve this as pretty as it is done in your C# code. This because of the type erasure done by the java compiler.

The best solution for you would probably be to use the Gson object at the location where you know the type of the object you need to serialize/deserialize.

If you're not keen on making instances of the Gson object everytime you can of course keep that one static at least, since it doesn't need any type parameters when created.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
public class GenericClass {

    private static Gson gson = new Gson(); 

    public static <T> T loadFromJSONString(String strRequest)
    {
        return (T) gson.fromJson(strRequest, T.class);
    }

    public static <T> String dumpToJSONString(T rq)
    {
        return gson.toJson(rq);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, wait. That won't work. This line causes problems:
return (T) gson.fromJson(strRequest, T.class);